# What typeface is used on the video game Artifact (card art)?

Tags: font-identification

https://liquipedia.net/commons/images/3/3e/Artifact_Hand_of_God.png <- sample of card art.

I have asked a new question for a similar font, as this font is not available for public use outside of Valve's products.

Comment: What font? Looks like the card uses 2 different fonts.

Comment: You're supposed to use the font search services first, then come here if you don't find it.

Comment: @AndrewH Looks like just narrow and regular variants of the same font to me.

Comment: Updated to mention that I have tried a font ID service. (Also there is a possibility that Valve is using its own custom typeface, but this is very unlikely.)

Comment: I dont think its so unlikely.

Comment: Also, this same font was used on the website of Dota 2 (a related game by the same company) since at least 2018.

Comment: If you mean the body text used on this website here: https://www.dota2.com/home - then it's a woff font called "Radiance" [see Firefox inspector screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/fAbKkLt). The Woff file says the font is copyright, and a protected Woff font. The vendor appears to be a company called "YouWorkForThem". I looked on their website but couldn't find the font listed. Trying to google "Radiance font" shows another font that looks nothing like this however.  It's entirely possible that this is a custom font that is not available for purchase.

Comment: Actual wording in the WOFF file says "This is a protected WebFont and is intended for CSS @font-face use ONLY. Reverse engineering this font is strictly prohibited and against all YouWorkForThem WebFont licensing usage rules. You may NOT use this WebFont file for desktop publishing. Copyright (c) , 2013. All rights reserved."

Comment: @BillyKerr It doesn't appear to be custom. Dota 2 (and Artifact) uses this typeface on parts of its UI but Dota haven't used it until 2015 when its UI was redesigned. (I have never played neither Dota 2 nor Artifact, so this may be hard to explain).

Comment: Try contacting the company that sold it/made it - YouWorkForThem. Anything else is really just speculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, the font name is Radiance and can direct download the file by clicking [here](https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/apps/dota2/fonts/radiance.ttf). But most likely you can not use it in any commercial project.